# MySQL storing images using hyperlinks

Tags: c#, mysql, storage

Good Day. So I have a question about storing images in Mysql.

My professor told us to change the data type of our column from blob to text.

And told us to store our images in a folder and not in the database itself and

just create a link stored in the column with the data type of text to link it to the directory of the images I want to show up in the db.

I don't know how to do it. I don't know how to use PHP.

My group is coding in C#.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are saving images in a directory  /your_project/images/image_name.png
Then just save the relative path in your database like 'images/image_name.png'.

And when you need to fetch that image then just get this value and prep-and it with your main directory_name  like  www.site_name.com/images/image_name.png 
You can change your main path when you move server .